# Can I compile a single .c file from the Nagios-Plugins package?

Tags: linux, plugins, compilation, monitoring, nagios

I'm wondering if I can compile just a single .c file like check_http.c in de source package of nagios-plugins-1.4.15 in the dir plugins. I'm about to add a piece of code to resolve a problem encountered by PNP4NAGIOS.

I want to compile this check_http and replace the old one in the libexec folder with this new one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this.  In fact, we have done it here.

Configure up the nagios-plugins source as you would normally do.  Then, edit your check_http.c file to make your changes, and from within the plugin source directory, just run 'make check_http' and it will compile just that.  If it claims that the file is already up to date, just 'rm check_http' and then 'make check_http'.

If it complains about a missing library (libcoreutils libnagiosplug) or  or other .o files, then this is because you have never run the initial compile to make the common libraries.  Go back to the base of the source tree, and do 'make all'.  Then, go back to the plugins directory and try 'make check_http'.